# Constructing enums using Z=> with variables instead of list literals

Tags: enums, raku

I would like to construct a String-typed enum.  The following works:

```
my Str enum E ( <a b c> Z=> 'one', 'two', 'three' );
E.kv.raku.say;
```

> ("c", "three", "a", "one", "b", "two").Seq

However, trying the following does not:

```
my Str @a = <a b c>;
my Str @b = <one two three>;
my Str enum F ( @a Z=> @b );
F.kv.raku.say;
```

> No values supplied to enum (does  @a Z=> @b  need to be declared constant?)

**Is this not supported?**

Raku/roast covers enum construction like in `E` but I didn't see any test cases for `F`.

Out of curiosity, I also tried:

```
my $a = <a b c>;
my $b = <one two three>;
my Str enum G ( $a<> Z=> $b<>.map( { .Str } ) );
G.kv.raku.say;
```

> ("", "").Seq

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning asks:

> does @a Z=> @b need to be declared constant

And it's correct; since an `enum` is a compile-time declaration, everything involved with computing its keys and values must be available at compile time. Declaring `@a` and `@b` as `constant`s resolves the problem. Thus:

```
my constant @a = <a b c>;
my constant @b = <one two three>;
my Str enum F ( @a Z=> @b );
F.kv.raku.say;
```

Produces:

```
("a", "one", "c", "three", "b", "two").Seq
```

Comment: ...so to summarize:  if you're writing a script or entering a one-liner at the shell command line, you'll run into problems if your arrays aren't `constant`s; but if you're working in the REPL, you might be able to get away without the `constant` declaration?

Comment: Yes; the very nature of a REPL is that line N has its runtime before the line N + 1 has its compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you let us know what Rakudo version? With`Rakudo™ v2022.07` and within the Raku REPL, I see virtually identical returns (i.e. no error):

```perl
~$ raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
```

```perl
[0] > my Str enum E ( <a b c> Z=> 'one', 'two', 'three' );
Map.new((a => one, b => two, c => three))
[1] > E.kv.raku.say;
("a", "one", "c", "three", "b", "two").Seq
```

```perl
[1] > my Str @a = <a b c>;
[a b c]
[2] > my Str @b = <one two three>;
[one two three]
[3] > my Str enum F ( @a Z=> @b );
Map.new((a => one, b => two, c => three))
[4] > F.kv.raku.say;
("b", "two", "a", "one", "c", "three").Seq
```

Comment: Rakudo v2022.07
Language v6.d
on MoarVM 2022.07

I don't know how the REPL works but if everything is entered together for one prompt, it results in the error shown in the question.